# A hash functin based on XOR and matrix multiplication

Tags: hash, one-way-function

Imagine an $n$ bit to $n$ bit hash function defined as follows: Let $K$ and $K'$ be two random predetermined $n\times n$ matrices. Then the hash function $h$ of an $n$ bit number $a$ would be:

$$h(a)=K\cdot a\oplus K'\cdot \bar{a}$$

Note that addition in matrix multiplication is done on one bit, so it's equivalent to $\oplus$ operation, Now my question is that if this function is reversible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that the following holds:

$$h(a)=K\cdot a+K'\cdot \bar a=K\cdot a+K'\cdot(a+1^n)=\underbrace{(K+K')}_M\cdot a+\underbrace{K'\cdot 1^n}_c=M\cdot a+c$$

Also note that $h(a)=M\cdot a$ is an universal hash function for $n$-bit input and $m$-bit output, as $\Pr\left[h(x)=h(y)\right]=2^{-m}$ with the randomness being over the choice of $M$. Clearly in this case $M=K+K'$ both of which are random matrices so this clearly holds. Now note that adding $c$ is essentially just a permutation over the bit values which doesn't change the collision properties, so it preserves the universality.

Also note that the first observation means that given $n+1$ chosen input-output pairs you can fully recover a description of $h$ and recover all information that you could from $Ma$ about $a$ when given $h(a)$. The strategy to the recovery would be to request $0^n$ and get $c$ this way. Then request $0^n$ with the $i$-th bit set for all $n$ values of $i$ to learn all the columns / rows of the $M$ matrix.